# how to use other tokenlizer(NLTK,Jiebe etc.) in tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, serving

Recently, I have been using estimator to train and deploy a tensorflow model, but when I deploy the model (it was exported using estimator `serving_fn` including `tf.py_func`) using tensorflow seving, there is an error (see below).

I found this question on Github that said the serving can't support `tf.py_func`.

Can anyone help?

I want to implement a token function using other `tokenlizer(NLTK,Jieba)`.

The error:

```
Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'PyFunc' used by {{node map/while/PyFunc}}with these attrs: [Tout=[DT_STRING], token="pyfunc_4", _output_shapes=[<unknown>], Tin=[DT_STRING]]
Registered devices: [CPU]
Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the tensorflow native tokenizer,eg. see https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/tensorflow_text/intro#tokenization